# Customizing user loss function with python(keras)

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

Hi Im trying to customize my own loss function. Loss function I'm trying to make is pixel wise loss(L2). So I coded like this

```
def image_loss(img1, img2):
  loss = 0 #initializing loss
  for n in range(0,3):
    for k in range(0,256):
      loss_prime = loss + np.sqrt((img1[0,k,k,n] - img2[0,k,k,n])^2)
      loss = loss_prime
  return loss


inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_CHANNELS),batch_size=1)
c1_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)  
#skipped layers between input and output                      
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (1,1), activation = 'tanh')(c18_2)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=image_loss(inputs,outputs))
```

But it showed an error and error says

```
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.bitwise.bitwise_xor_2" (type TFOpLambda).

Value passed to parameter 'x' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int8, int16, int32, int64, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64

Call arguments received:
x=tf.Tensor(shape=(), dtype=float32)
y=2
name=None
```

What is the problem??

Comment: You have two problems, you cannot use numpy functions in a keras loss, instead use backend functions, and the traceback does not match this code, you should include the complete traceback.

Comment: I understood what you meant by we cannot use numpy function in keras so use backend. But Im sorry but I not sure about what traceback is and include the complete traceback means. Do you have any reference of maybe website address for traceback so I can look up? Anyway thanks for help :)